# Optimize MySQL self join

Tags: mysql, self-join

I have self join query on table with 4 million records....how can we optimize the query...query has to fetch rows with max date

```
  SELECT DISTINCT d1.C1 AS c1, d1.C2 AS c2, d1.C3 AS c3,
         d1.datedm_id AS c4 FROM TABLEA d1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEA d2 
         ON (d1.C1 = d2.C1 AND d1.C2 = d2.C2 AND d1.datedm_id < d2.datedm_id ) 
         WHERE d2.C1 IS NULL AND d2.C2 IS NULL
```

Currently this query takes very long to execute

EXPLAIN shows following

```
d1 4051368  Using index; Using temporary
d2 1    Using where; Using index; Not exists; Distinct
```

Comment: are C1 and C2 indexed?

Comment: have you tried EXPLAIN? Also, DISTINCT may not be the same as GROUP BY, but in many cases it will yield the same results, and may be way faster. + if possible avoid outer joins and use inner joins instead (don't know anything besides the stuff you posted)

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` before the `SELECT` and see what it shows?  What indexes do you have on the table(s)?

Answer (score 0):

To optimize this query, build an index on `tableA(C1, C2, datedm_id)`.

You can rewrite it as:

```
SELECT d1.C1 AS c1, d1.C2 AS c2, d1.C3 AS c3, d1.datedm_id AS c4
FROM TABLEA d1
WHERE not exists (select 1
                  from TABLEA d2 
                  where d1.C1 = d2.C1 AND d1.C2 = d2.C2 AND d1.datedm_id < d2.datedm_id
                 );
```

This version should definitely use the index.  The first version should, but might not under all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select d1.C1 AS c1, d1.C2 AS c2, d1.C3 AS c3,
     d1.datedm_id AS c4 FROM TABLEA d1
where not exists(
  select 'nextdatedm'
  from TABLEA d2
  where d1.C1 = d2.C1 AND d1.C2 = d2.C2 AND d1.datedm_id < d2.datedm_id
)
```

I've replaced your LEFT OUTER JOIN with EXISTS function (in this solution I'll get only TABLEA where not exists another row with datedm more young).

In this way you can remove the DISTINCT function.

To complete your task, you can add some index about comparing fields